# AJAX take data from POST with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a little problem with my script.
I want to give data to a php file with AJAX (POST).

I dont get any errors, but the php file doesn't show a change after AJAX "runs" it.
Here is my jquery / js code:
(#changeRank is a select box, I want to pass the value of the selected )

```
$(function(){
$("#changeRank").change(function() {
    var rankId = this.value;
    //alert(rankId);
    //$.ajax({url: "/profile/parts/changeRank.php", type: "post", data: {"mapza": mapza}});
    //$("body").load("/lib/tools/popups/content/ban.php");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: '/profile/parts/changeRank.php',
    data:  { 'direction': 'up' },
    success: function (msg) 
            { alert('success') },
    error: function (err)
    { alert(err.responseText)}
    });
});
});
```

PHP:

```
require_once('head.php');
require_once('../../lib/permissions.php');
session_start();
$user = "test";
if($_SESSION["user"] != $user && checkPermission("staff.fakeLogin", $_SESSION["user"], $mhost, $muser, $mpass, $mdb))
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
header('Location:/user/'.$user);
die();
```

When i run the script, javascript comes up with an alert "success" which means to me, that there aren't any problems.

I know, the post request for my data is missing, but this is only a test, so im planning to add this later...

I hope, you can help me,
Greets :)

Comment: What exactly do you expect. `alert succes` means that the request returned a `200 message` indicating that the request was a success, however that's all it says.

Comment: yeah, i want to say to you, that the problem has nothing to do with my jquery code, has it ?

Comment: Indeed, the jQuery (javascript) is functioning fine. What do you expect server side in the PHP file?

Comment: i just want a life signal (echo or an redirect, ...), so i can be sure, that there is "a connection" UPDATE: the code in php works, however i want to echo something after the php script, greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$("#changeRank").change(function() {
    var rankId = this.value;
    //alert(rankId);
    //$.ajax({url: "/profile/parts/changeRank.php", type: "post", data: {"mapza": mapza}});
    //$("body").load("/lib/tools/popups/content/ban.php");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: '/profile/parts/changeRank.php',
    data:  { 'direction': 'up' },
    success: function (msg) 
            { alert('success: ' + JSON.stringify(msg)) },
    error: function (err)
    { alert(err.responseText)}
    });
});
});


require_once('head.php');
require_once('../../lib/permissions.php');
session_start();
$user = "test";
if($_SESSION["user"] != $user && checkPermission("staff.fakeLogin", $_SESSION["user"], $mhost, $muser, $mpass, $mdb))
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
echo json_encode($user);
```

This sample code will let echo the username back to the page. The alert should show this.

Answer (score 0):

well your js is fine, but because you're not actually echoing out anything to your php script, you wont see any changes except your success alert.  maybe var_dump your post variable to check if your data was passed from your js file correctly...

Comment: hey, the script (php) works fine, but i cant echo something. when i make a change in my session array, everything is fine, until i want to echo something - nothing happens (nothing visible).

Comment: oh ok try using var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

Just return `0` or `1` from your php like this

Your PHP :

```
if($_SESSION["user"] != $user && checkPermission("staff.fakeLogin", $_SESSION["user"], $mhost, $muser, $mpass, $mdb))
{
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
echo '1'; // success case
}
else
{
echo '0'; // failure case
}
```

Then in your script

```
success: function (msg) 
if(msg==1)
{
window.location = "home.php"; // or your success action
}
else
{
alert('error);
}
```

So that you can get what you expect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a result, in the current page, using data from your PHP then you need to do two things:

1. Actually send some from the PHP. Your current PHP redirects to another URL which might send data. You could use that or remove the `Location` header and `echo` some content out instead.
2. Write some JavaScript that does something with that data. The data will be put into the first argument of the success function (which you have named `msg`). If you want that data to appear in the page, then you have to put it somewhere in the page (e.g. with `$('body').text(msg)`.